# Rails accessing mongo _id from HTTPS post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, mongodb

I have a portal running Rails, attempting to get information from an image server with mongoDB (running Node).  I'm baffled as to how to get the _id of the submission (name of the collection), as it errors out when I try.

This works fine, returns another attribute of submission:

```
function portal_request (req, res, next) {
    Submission.findOne({ imagedate: req.body.imagedate })
        .exec()
        .then(function (data) {
            res.status(200).end(data.image_buffer);
                return;
        }, function (err) {
            res.status(409).end(err);
            return;
        });
}
```

But if I change that one line to give me the id instead:

```
res.status(200).end(data._id);
```

I go from receiving 200 responses, to 502 (Bad Gateway). I have no idea why, any clues?